# Why a syntax error is leading to a infinite loop instead of a fatal error at compiling time?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32

I make the following mistake in a for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<(blockSize);i=+2)
```

**i=+2** instead of **i+=2**

The result was crazy, no compiler error but a nice infinite loop. 
I had gone crazy...

Why I did have an error? Is this a bug or not? Can some one explain it?

I am using gcc for ARM Micro-controllers.

Comment: It's not a syntax error! The third clause in the for loop assigns +2, which is actually 2, to `i`. And 2 is less than blockSize so infinite loop.

Comment: `+=` is an operator, but `=+` is not. It's treated like `= +`

Comment: @klutt now I know, but was very difficult to see this error and why not a warning from the compiler?? Loop is infinitive??

Comment: @poprock You cannot expect a compiler to warn for EVERY little thing. :)

Comment: Compiler cannot determine if some piece of code will result in infinite loop reliably, nor can it determine that you didn’t actually want to write such a thing. Therefore no warning will be given. There are no rules saying that the last part needs to be increment or decrement, it can be whatever. There’s no reasonable way to give a warning.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen One could reasonably argue that a `=` followed by a `+` should always generate a warning, because that's something that I have never ever used, and I cannot even see a use case for it. On the other hand, this is the first time ever that I've seen this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because `i=+2` is being interpreted as `i = +2` ("i equals positive two"). `i` is being set to `2` after every loop, meaning your loop never ends.

[`+` and `-` can both be placed in front of numbers to specify their signs in `C`.](https://repl.it/repls/ScaryCriticalSoftware)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming blockSize > 2, i =+2 is identical to i = 2, so the loop never completes because i is not incremented.

Comment: Why not a warning?